# JIRA get stored pluginSettings in velocity / onchange

Tags: servlets, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

i am still pretty new to JIRA DEV.

To summarize,
I created a plugin wich can store some date via pluginSettings
(https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Storing+plugin+settings)

So now my question is how can i achieve an update on my values once i select another Project in for example a SelectOneMenu.

First i add some parameters to my velocity context so that i can read the pluginSettingsValues.

My Servlet

```js
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        
        VelocityTemplatingEngine templatingEngine = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(VelocityTemplatingEngine.class);
        
        PluginSettings pluginSettings = pluginSettingsFactory.createGlobalSettings();
        
        Map<String, Object> velocityParams =   ComponentAccessor.getVelocityParamFactory().getDefaultVelocityParams();
        velocityParams.put("projectManager", ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager());
        velocityParams.put("pluginSettings", pluginSettings);
              
        templatingEngine.render(file("ticketSettings.vm"))
            .applying(velocityParams)
            .asPlainText(response.getWriter()); 
}
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PluginSettings pluginSettings = pluginSettingsFactory.createGlobalSettings();
    
    pluginSettings.put(PROJECT_TICKET + "." +req.getParameter("Projects") + "." + req.getParameter("Prio") + ".editTime", req.getParameter("EditTime"));
    pluginSettings.put(PROJECT_TICKET + "." +req.getParameter("Projects") + "." + req.getParameter("Prio") + ".reactionTime", req.getParameter("ReactionTime"));
 
response.sendRedirect("ticketsettings");
}
```

In my Velocity is a simple select element and the target container

```html
<--! Select Menu -->
<select class="select" id="dProj" name="Projects" title="project select">
  #foreach ($pr in $projectManager.getProjectObjects())
         <option>$pr.getName()</option>
   #end    
</select>
 
<--! Conmtent Container -->
<div>
<label>PluginSettings: </label><label>$pluginSettings.get('key')</label>
</div>
```

The data is of course updated when i submit the form.

What i want to achieve is, that on every onchange Event fired by the select element i want a visual update in my container where i show the actual data.

The key-value should be the selected item from dProj